# Ipad - storing data from a webform

Tags: html, xcode, ipad, forms, data-storage

I have a simple form on a web page. I've got an ipad that is going to be used in a room with no 3g or internet connection.

How can I store the results of all the data that is submitted through the form, so that later, i can just download that data or export it somewhere?

What's the quickest way?

without having to recreate the entire form in xcode?

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such little data to store, [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is probably the way to go.

Save a string:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"]];
```

Retrieve a string:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Comment: So are you saying that I could submit my form and then read what was submitted in xcode?

Comment: @Jason: I didn't realize you're using HTML. How long is your form? Recreating in Interface Builder may be the best way to go. You would be able to store the data and retrieve it later using Xcode. As far as I know, it's not easily possible to read data from the UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to serve the web page with no internet connection?  Are you including it in an App then using WebView to display it?  If so you should be able to use something like SQLite to save the data, then later have an "administrator" side where you can view the entrees in the Database.

Comment: Yes that's right. but here's the kicker, can i read posted form data from xcode? i think that the answer is no

Comment: Not that I know of.  If its plugged in the whole time you could use NSLog to write to the console but not after the fact.